# Statistics Probability Distribution

Tags: statistics

A team of 4 is to be randomly chosen from 3 boys and 5 girls. The random variable X is the number of girls in the team. A probability distribution table for X is shown.

X

1

2

3

4

P(X=x)

a

b

c

d

What is the  Var (x) if E(X)=5/2 .

Please give your final answer in 4 decimal.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a hypergeometric distribution with probatility mass function given by

$$P(X=k) = \frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{N-n}{M-k}}{\binom{N}{M}}$$

where

$N=8$ is the number of girls and boys

$M=5$ is the number of girls

$n=4$ is the number of draws

$k$ is the number of observed successes

Now we have $$\mathrm{E}[X] = n\frac{M}{N} = 4\cdot\frac{5}{8} = \frac{5}{2}$$ and $$\mathrm{Var}[X] = n\frac{M}{N}\left(1-\frac{M}{N}\right)\frac{N-n}{N-1} = 4\cdot\frac{5}{8}\left(1-\frac{5}{8}\right)\frac{4}{7} = \frac{15}{28}\approx 0.5357$$